# How to Histogram Unitful Units in Julia?

Tags: julia, composition

I am trying to figure out how to bin/histogram an array of data in Julia. I have an array of units from the `Unitful.jl` package and want to use `Histogram` from `StatsBase` to bin the data. The first error I got was an error saying there were no methods for `log10` to use `Unitful.FreeUnits` so I wrote one. Now I get a dimensional error. I thought Unitful was just going to work with other stuff.. guess not. The following is where I am at.

```
using Unitful
using StatsBase

data = [rand()*100*1u"MHz" for x in 1:10000]

function Base.log10(x::Quantity{})
    u = unit(x)
    return log10(x.val)u
end

# eventually I want to define my bin width manually.. but this is a start.
fit(Histogram, data)
```

**ERROR**

```
ERROR: DimensionError: 0.0 and 0.8237981449864736 MHz are not dimensionally compatible.
Stacktrace:
 [1] _lt at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/Unitful/1t88N/src/quantities.jl:274 [inlined]
 [2] <(::Quantity{Float64,NoDims,Unitful.FreeUnits{(),NoDims,nothing}}, ::Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}}) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/Unitful/1t88N/src/quantities.jl:264
 [3] <(::Int64, ::Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}}) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/Unitful/1t88N/src/quantities.jl:266
 [4] <=(::Int64, ::Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}}) at ./operators.jl:326
 [5] >=(::Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}}, ::Int64) at ./operators.jl:350
 [6] histrange(::Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}}, ::Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}}, ::Int64, ::Symbol) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:51
 [7] histrange(::Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}, ::Int64, ::Symbol) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:39
 [8] (::StatsBase.var"#127#128"{Symbol})(::Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}, ::Int64) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:103
 [9] map(::StatsBase.var"#127#128"{Symbol}, ::Tuple{Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}}, ::Tuple{Int64}) at ./tuple.jl:176
 [10] histrange(::Tuple{Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}}, ::Tuple{Int64}, ::Symbol) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:102
 [11] fit(::Type{Histogram{Int64,N,E} where E where N}, ::Tuple{Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}}; closed::Symbol, nbins::Int64) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:332
 [12] fit(::Type{Histogram{Int64,N,E} where E where N}, ::Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}; closed::Symbol, nbins::Int64) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:276
 [13] fit(::Type{Histogram{Int64,N,E} where E where N}, ::Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:276
 [14] fit(::Type{Histogram}, ::Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}; kwargs::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:383
 [15] fit(::Type{Histogram}, ::Array{Quantity{Float64,^-1,Unitful.FreeUnits{(MHz,),^-1,nothing}},1}) at /home/mcamp/.julia/packages/StatsBase/EA8Mh/src/hist.jl:383
 [16] top-level scope at REPL[183]:1
 [17] run_repl(::REPL.AbstractREPL, ::Any) at /build/julia/src/julia-1.5.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.5/REPL/src/REPL.jl:288
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED because I misunderstood the question]

Are you looking to plot a histogram of the data? If yes, instead of StatsBase.jl, I would use the `histogram` function of a plotting package like Plots.jl. For instance, to combine plots from Plots.jl with units from Unitful.jl, you can use the [UnitfulRecipes.jl](https://github.com/jw3126/UnitfulRecipes.jl) package. See this MWE that may be what you are after:

```
using Unitful: MHz
using Plots
using UnitfulRecipes
data = 100 * exp.(randn(10000)) * MHz
histogram(data)
```

will output

[image: histogram of data with units]

---

[BEFORE EDIT]

I don't think it makes sense mathematically or physically to take the logarithm of a non-nondimensional variable (i.e., a variable with a unit). That is, your redefinition of `log10` is not a good idea IMHO. Instead, I would non-dimensionalize the data before taking the log, with something similar to

```
using Unitful: MHz
using StatsBase
data = 100 * rand(10000) * MHz
data_nodim = log10.(data / MHz) # <- this is valid
fit(Histogram, data_nodim)      # <- this is valid too
```

Comment: this isn't what I am looking to do.. I want to bin or histogram data with units. So say I have an array of 1000 measurements in MHz that have a range of 40MHz to 1000Mhz. I want to bin the data in order to get an understanding of its distribution. I'm not sure how `StatsBase` is using `log10`.. but I was just trying to some how make the thing work. 

maybe I just need to modify the Histogram that gets made and changes its edges to be units or something..

Comment: Oh I see, I also see you posted [an issue on Unitful.jl](https://github.com/PainterQubits/Unitful.jl/issues/408). I'll chime in there then :)

Comment: Actually I will answer here first, by editing my answer :)